# Complex polynomials and cofficients problem

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I've searched for an answer on Khan Academy, but I could only find with known coefficients. I also asked my classmates, but so far nobody has figured out an answer. I have previously worked with the division algorithm, and couldn't figure out if it would apply to this task.

$i$ is the imaginary number.

$p(z) = a_3z^3+a_2z^2+a_1z+a_0 $

Has the known roots

$6, i, -2i $

and

$p(-i)=1-6i$

Calculate the coefficients $a_3, a_2, a_1, a_0$ on rectangular form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a_0=-6i\\a_1=3+i\\a_2=-\frac12-3i\\a_3=\frac i2.\end{array}\right.$$This is so because $p(z)=K(z-6)(z-i)(z+2i)$ for some $K\in\mathbb C$. It follows from the equality $p(-i)=1-6i$ that $K=\frac i2$. Therefore,\begin{align}p(z)&=\frac i2(z-6)(z-i)(z+2i)\\&=\frac i2z^3+\left(-\frac12-3i\right)z^2+(3+i)z-6i.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm not excactly sure as to why k=i/2

Comment: @JonathanWinther Since $p(z)=K(z-6)(z-i)(z+2i)$, $1-6i=p(-i)=K(-i-6)(-i-i)(-i+2i)$. Therefore$$K=\frac{1-6i}{(-i-6)(-i-i)(-i+2i)}=\frac i2.$$

Comment: @JonathanWinther I'm glad I could help. I have a suggestion for you: the next time you post a question here about complex numbers, don't waste time explaining us that $i$ is the imaginary unit.